# Автоматическая ассоциация протокола в браузере

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, браузер, webbrowser, protocol

Написал я пользовательский протокол для windows, зарегистрировал его и всё работает. Однако при каждом открытии ссылки формата "MyProtocol://..." браузер редиректит на другую страницу, и спрашивает, открывать ли ссылку в приложении.

Мне бы хотелось убрать подобные окна так, что бы браузер сам ассоциировал и выполнял протокол. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

P.S. Браузер Chrome. Копаю в сторону расширений, но насколько прав - не знаю.